# How to assign data to value attribute in input tag, pulled by firebase database?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I used the code snippet below to pull data from Firebase database and assign it to the `Name` variable.

```
var userId = localStorage.getItem('keyName');

var dbRefName = firebase.database().ref()
                                   .child('Web App')
                                   .child('Users')
                                   .child(userId)
                                   .child('Name');

dbRefName.on('value', snap => Name.innerText = snap.val());

var Name = document.getElementById('Name');
```

Then, I try to assign the `Name` variable to `value` attribute of the `input` tag like this:

```
<input type="text"
       id="Name"
       class="form-control form-control-alternative"
       placeholder="User Name"
       value="Name">
```

But it is not working, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

add this line 

`var Name = document.getElementById('Name');
document.getElementById("Name").value = Name;`

and remove `value="Name"` from your html

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by my self. experience the excellence. Here it is

```
var userId = localStorage.getItem('keyName');

    var dbRefName = firebase.database().ref().child('Web App').child('Users').child(userId).child('Name');

     dbRefName.on("value", function(snapshot) {
      console.log(snapshot.val());

      document.getElementById('Name').value = snapshot.val();

    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
```

And the input tag should be looked like here.

```
<input type="text"
       id="Name"
       class="form-control form-control-alternative"
       placeholder="User Name"
       >
```